# Facebook. Maximum number of requests allocated to your application

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, multi-friend-selector

I have a Facebook aplication on my site with `multi friend selector` which posts to selected friends.
When I test it on local host all works fine, but when I upload it to live server on the last step of sending when I click post to my selected friends, there is a pop-up warning saying :

> Sorry, you have run out of requests to sent with this application.
>   Please try again tomorrow

But it was my first post on the live server... What options or something else should I change to avoid this warning?

### Added from comments

```
<fb:serverfbml width= "740" height="407" > 
    <script type="text/fbml"> 
        <fb:request-form action="%%POSTCARD_ACTION_URL%%?at=send_postcard" method="POST" type="POSTCARD" content='Click the View button to see the Postcard sent to you. <fb:req-choice url="%%FACEBOOK_ACTION_URL%%?view=%%hash%%" label="View">' invite="false">
            <input type="hidden" name="mail_hash" id ="mail_hash" value="%%hash%%"> 
            <fb:multi-friend-selector style="width:80%;" showborder="false" actiontext="Select the friends you want send postcard." rows="3" bypass="cancel" email_invite="false" />
        </fb:request-form> 
    </script> 
</fb:serverfbml>
```

I am using a `multi-friend-selector` wraped into `serverfbml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were testing your application's invite feature, and deleted the requests when the application was **not** in sand box mode, then all the request rejections were calculated into the "user feedback" of your application....

Once facebook's systems have decided that your application has received enough negative feedback,they will start limiting your application's features.  One such feature that they can limit is requests...
All limitations enforced on your application can be viewed in the [Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/) >> Diagnostics  tab in your application's settings.
With regard to initial invite limitations, when you start developing your application, AFAIK, you have a limit of 50 requests **per user**, per day as shown below :
[image]

### UPDATE

After some further discussion and updating the original question, It seems that you are using the old method of inviting friends - [FBML](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/).  As you can see from the documentation pages of FBML, they are in the process of (and nearly finished) removing their support for it.

> **We are deprecating FBML. On Jan 1, 2012: FBML will no longer be
>   supported on Platform. June 1, 2012**: FBML apps will no longer work.
>   All FBML endpoints are removed. If you are building a new application
>   on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML,
>   JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins
>   to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML.

You should seriously consider migrating to use the newer [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).  All the information you need is in link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

You'll need to use the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and after setting it up and calling the `FB.init()` function, you'll want to make a call to the `FB.ui()` function and tell it to open the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

---

### Further Update

After filing a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/118656198255959?browse=search_4f16eb2da4a9a2565741824) to do with the incorrect displaying of Request 1.0 when the application from which the screenshot was taken was set to use Request 2.0, Facebook replied to the [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/118656198255959?browse=search_4f16eb2da4a9a2565741824) first by "confirming and assigning" (see older responses in the bug report) and then stating that this "by design" will be removed as soon as FBML is totally deprecated.  Facebook also stated :

> Request 2.0 does not have limits as 1.0 did.

Good to know :P

Comment: Yea - this screenshot was also taken from an app with `Request 2.0`... hmmm... *"me feels a bug report coming on..."* lol

Comment: Can you please update your original post with more information such as code samples of how you are implementing the request dialog?

Comment: What method i must use in friends selector to post on they wall or just geting theyr ID. In FB requests dialog documentaion told about `apprequests` only

Comment: Please read my answer carefully - you should not be using the "friend-selector" any more...  What you need to use is the "requests dialog" and that is the "apprequests" method that you are talking about.  In the link to the documentation that I posted there is all the information about the dialog and how to use it.  Note: posting on a wall is not the same as inviting a user.

Comment: When i say multifriend selector i means requests dialog, in documentation told about invites, but i don`t wona to invite friends, i just wont to take slected IDs, and then call `$facebook->api("","post", $args)`

Comment: The way to get them is send requests, read response, get selected users id and delete requests? And then just send with fb->api to this ids?

Comment: What are you wanting to do?  Send an invite to your application? Or post a message on a users wall?  In your question you were only talking about sending invites....

Comment: I wont to post messages on users wall(feed), which i selected in this dialog. What should i do for it?

Comment: This is a different thing altogether my friend.  Please post a **new question** talking about posting messages on friends walls.  (or search for an answer here on stackoverflow).